# Safely close/remove file for ImageView in JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application which displays all images from a certain folder in a VBox. The VBox is built like this:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(imagePath)) {
    for (Path file : stream) {
        String fileNameLc = file.toString().toLowerCase();
        if (fileNameLc.matches(".*\\.(jpg|png)")) {
            ImageView graph = new ImageView(new Image(Files.newInputStream(file)));
            graph.setPreserveRatio(true);
            imageVBox.getChildren().add(graph);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //
}
```

There also is a button to remove all images (and all other files) in the folder which are displayed in the VBox. This is the code for the button action:

```
imageVBox.getChildren().clear();
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(imagePath)) {
    for (Path file : stream) {
        Files.delete(file);
        System.out.println("Removing: " + file);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //
}
```

Displaying the images works fine, but deleting them does not work. In the standard output I see

```
Removing: /foo/img1.jpg
Removing: /foo/img2.jpg
...
```

No Exceptions are thrown, but the image files are still there if check the contents of the folder. All files in the folder which are not images (and are not displayed in the VBox) are removed succesfully, but the images displayed in the VBox are not.

I thinks the cause is that after

```
imageVBox.getChildren().clear();
```

a background thread starts to remove the images and the .clear() method returns immediately. This way the code block which removes the files is executed before the Image resources are closed.

What would be be the best way to close the images? and why is there no Exception thrown by the Files.delete() method?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I don't really buy your explanation: there is no background thread created to remove the `ImageView`s from the `VBox`, and the file handle should be released once the image data is read anyway. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The files displayed in the imageviews are the only ones that are not deleted, thats what makes me think that the imageviews are not releasing the images resources. I'll try to write an MVCE sometime this week. I also noticed that this problem is only occurring on Windows 7, not on win8 or Linux (all using Oracle Java SE 8).

Comment: OK, I'm on a Mac, so maybe that's why I can't reproduce it. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a realy old question, but i think anyone can have the same problem, i have it few days ago.

The problem is realy simple when you create yout ImageView, the image are load by JAVA, and you can't delete it before free the memory.

I don't know why they are no error, but you can see an error if you try to delete
the image file manualy during the execution of jar.

For free the ImageView you have to do that :

```
Image graph = new Image(Files.newInputStream(file));
ImageView graphView = new ImageView(graph);

graph = null;
graphView.setImage(null);
System.gc();
```

Don't forget System.gc(), that will call the garbage collector and he will free memory and after that you can now delete the file.

Enjoy,

Sorry for the realy bad english

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's an interesting way to solve the problem but it looks a bit hacky to me. I kind of worked around the problem by copying all images to a temporary folder and then reading the image files from that temp folder. I then remove the all the temp folders when the application is closed, and also every time the application is started. This solutions seems to work perfectly on all operation systems