# how to close an opened Image, java/javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a simple picture viewer with `java`, using `javafx`
after opening about 10 pics, it takes lots of ram!

obviously I need to properly close the opened pics (that are not showing right now!) (in my test/use cases, pics are huge!!)

this is only a piece of the code...
but it's everything needed to know

```
private HashMap<Image, String> adrs;     // a hashMap from thumbNail to address of the image
ObservableList<ImageView> list;          // list of thumbNails
@FXML public ListView<ImageView> pics;
@FXML public ImageView preview;

public void init(String[] picAdrs){

    loadThumbNails(picAdrs);                    // initializes thumbNails (list)
    pics.setItems(list);

    pics.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v, oldvalue, newvalue) -> {
        // --> this is where the previous value of "preview.getImage()" should be closed <--
        // (and i don't know how!)
        preview.setImage( new Image(adrs.get(newvalue.getImage()));
        // and more (not related codes...)
    }
}

private void loadThumbNails(String[] picAdrs){
    // initializing list & adrs
    for(String i : picAdrs){

        Image img = new Image(new File(i).toURI().toString(), 200, 0, true, false);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView();
        iv.setImage(img);  

        adrs.put(img, new File(i).toURI().toString());
        list.add(iv);
    }


}
```

thumbNails are on left side and "preview" is on the right:
[Just a preview of the Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBGwD.png)

as it seems to be really simple! ... a simple way would be appreciated!
btw... the code works, it's only about the part that i commented

I reduced about 50% ram usage using garbage collector but **I still want a better way** as i know `system.gc` is not reliable

here is a log for opening 30 thumbnails and one full quality pic:
[image]

Comment: Try checking out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325996/safely-close-remove-file-for-imageview-in-javafx

Comment: Please post the code responsible for loading the pictures and describe how the user swaps between different pics.

Comment: @Collins.A this post is about deleting... already read it... tnx anyway

Comment: @fabian code and a screen shot added... user can preview a pic by selecting its thumb nail from thumbNails ("pics" has a listener for that)

Comment: Have you used [vusualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) or something like that? If not ... the memory may be available for garbage collection even though it's not actually freed...

Comment: my ide is eclipse... is it a VM? @fabian

Comment: VisualVM (typo in the last comment, oops) is a tool that comes with the JDK... (click at the link in the last comment). I don't know whether eclipse allows you to access this kind of functionality.

Comment: @SASA1024 how are you measuring the memory usage?

Comment: in task manager... i checked for my other codes, and this one is differently too much... like 30-40 times more! @James_D

Comment: Task manager in Windows? All that is going to do is show you the total amount of RAM assigned to the Java heap, whether or not the JVM is actually using it. Use a proper profiling tool such as VisualVM, as suggested. As long as the images do not have references retained the memory is available to be reclaimed when it is needed.

Comment: yeah in windows... after your last comment i used VisualVm to monitor memory usage... i'll add it to Q @James_D

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all references to the Image.  There is a reference to the Image in the ImageView, so you will either need to remove any references to the ImageView also, or set the image field in the ImageView to null.

I see three collections in your code where references to Image's or ImageViews can linger.

```
private HashMap<Image, String> adrs;     // a hashMap from thumbNail to address of the image
ObservableList<ImageView> list;          // list of thumbNails
@FXML public ListView<ImageView> pics;
```

You going to have to find a way to remove these objects from these collections.  As long as they are in there they will take up ram.

What I would consider doing is instead of storing the Image & ImageView objects themselves, maybe store URL's to them.  A URL can point to a file or http location.  Then load it in real time.  If you want to load everything ahead of time, well then ram use is the cost.

Also, during your travels look into WeakHashMap.  It is a Map that will remove old references for you, which would free up your ram.  So that way you only have to focus on adding Images/ImageViews to your collection and let Java's WeakHashMap remove them.

Comment: Seems like all references to a full-sized image are already removed, when the image inside the `preview` `ImageView` is replaced. Also the `Image`s in `adrs` and `list` already seem to be downsampled.

Comment: the only things that i load are thumbnails and addresses (urls?)
with every pic selected, an image fully loads into preview and with the next pic selected, the previous image (in preview, which has no references anymore) stays in ram

Comment: @fabian what about replacing preview with a new ImageView versus swapping the Image field?

Comment: @JoseMartinez: I tested this some time ago and for some reason the `Image` data was not available for garbage collection when I just removed the `ImageView` from the parent's child list, but it was available when I replaced the image in the `ImageView` with `null` (and replacing a `Image` would most likely work too).

Answer (score 0):

so far it seems there isn't a simple way...
`finilize()` might be useful... (but don't know how to use it yet!)

with answers from [delete-unused-variables-memory-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330812/delete-unused-variables-memory-in-java) i managed to reduce the ram usage to less than 100mb. but since it's using gc, it's not reliable (the `System.gc` command might not run the gc)